# Integrate $3^{-4x^2}dx$ using gamma functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble solving this integral from 0 to infinity, I want to get it to the form $e^{-ax}x^b$, but I can't do it when trying to use tricks such as putting the function to ln then to the power of $e,$ then using the substitution $u=\ln(3^{-4x^2})$.  Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$\int_0^\infty 3^{-4x^2}\, dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-(4\ln 3)x^2}\, dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-(4\ln 3)u}u^{-1/2}\, du,$$

using $u = x^2$ in the last step. Letting $v = (4\ln 3)u$, we get

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-(4\ln 3)u}u^{-1/2}\, du = \frac{1}{2(4\ln 3)^{1/2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-v}v^{-1/2}\, dv = \frac{1}{2(\ln 81)^{1/2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\ln 81}}.$$